# How to handle dynamic keys with single element as value in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having a problem figuring out how to handle dynamic keys with a single value one level deep. I've seen a few examples but they appear to handle other cases.

Here's an example.

```
[
  { "asdofjiodi": "asdofidj.com" },
  { "sadjlkj": "iejjol.com" },
  { "ijijwjljlijl": "adsijf.com" },
  { "jgncmkz": "mlkjaoijf.com" }
]
```

Any ideas on how I accomplish this with `Codable` or `CodingKey`? This is what I'd like for the end result.

```
["asdofidj.com", "iejjol.com", "adsijf.com", "mlkjaoijf.com"]
```

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
// NOTE: The below line doesn't work because I'm not sure how to do the encoding/decoding
try? decoder.decode([[String: String]].self, from: data)
```

Comment: You could decode into `[String: String]` and iterate on values ignoring the keys

Comment: @NewDev ahh, I thought I tried that and it didn't work. Thanks, I'm sure I did it wrong. I'll try again.

Comment: Make sure that the JSON is properly formatted (your example is not a valid JSON; it would need to be inside `{` `}` brackets), and it's best not to use `try?` - use `try` inside `do/catch` and handle/print any errors.

Comment: @Petesta It is not valid JSON.

Comment: @George_E I had formatted the above for Swift. That’s why it didn’t look like valid JSON and caused confusion. It was ambiguous. It’s formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is not a valid JSON. A "Valid JSON" can be a JSON Array (multiple json objects) or a single JSON object (starts and ends with `{` and `}`)

After cleaning this...

You are trying to make a dictionary (json object) from a data. You don't need `JSONDecoder` to accomplish this. Try using `JSONSerialization` with jsonObject static function...

```
let data = Data("{\"asdofjiodi\": \"asdofidj.com\",\"sadjlkj\": \"iejjol.com\",\"ijijwjljlijl\": \"adsijf.com\",\"jgncmkz\": \"mlkjaoijf.com\"}".utf8)
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
let values = json?.map({ $1 })
print(values)
```

I Hope I helped!

[JSONSerialization Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example, given the JSON in your question:

```
let json = """
[
  { "asdofjiodi": "asdofidj.com" },
  { "sadjlkj": "iejjol.com" },
  { "ijijwjljlijl": "adsijf.com" },
  { "jgncmkz": "mlkjaoijf.com" }
]
"""

let data = Data(json.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let decodedJson = try decoder.decode([[String: String]].self, from: data)
    let values = decodedJson.compactMap(\.values.first)
    print(values)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

If this doesn't appear to work for you, it may be related to how you load in the JSON.